# How I load xml file from my smartphone to my app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have some problemas when I try load xml file from my smartphone to my app (react-native)... I used this API: https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs but but I can't get it to work...

Someone?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? What code are you running? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: thank you for support... Error: "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNF Manager.RNF FileType Regular')"... After I install react-native-fs library and ''var RNFS = require(react-native-fs')